# What is this white-flowered ground cover plant?

Tags: identification, flowers, ground-cover

I'd like to know what this white-flowered,  winter-hardy ground cover plant with lacerate(?) leaves? Up to 15cm high. It has flowers: The diameter of the flowers is about 2 cm.

(click for a larger version)

[image: while-flowered]

**UPDATE:** I added two pictures which zoom on the leaves and one which shows the whole ground its covering. Again click to enlargen:

[image: ground] [image: leaves]

Comment: It looks like a saxifrage but the ones I know have five petalled flowers not four.

Comment: I started a bounty because I really like to have an answer. Please do not hesitate to ask for more information which is currently missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, just 5 minutes after starting the bounty I think I found it on another site: it seems to be [Garden Arabis, *Arabis caucasica*](http://en.hortipedia.com/wiki/Arabis_alpina_subsp._caucasica).

Comment: I believe you are right and have plus 1 it.The four petals, white flowers, lacinate leaves point to the cultivar 'Snowcap' ('Alpina Snowcap' or 'Schneehaube,') a vigorous drought-hardy White Rock Cress or Wall Cress (Arabis caucasica, formerly A. albida), thriving in a full sun location with very little water.